# Can I draw a line on a html5 canvas with variable widths per segment?

Tags: html, canvas

I would like to draw a multiple segment line on a html 5 canvas with variable width per segment.

I tried something like (pseudocode):

```
beginpath()
setLineWidth(1)
lineTo(0,0)
...
setLineWidth(10)
lineTo(73, 44)

stroke()
```

but it seems stroke only takes the last linewidth() value? Is there another way?

I tried making every segment its own line, but that turned out really really show when drawing 1000+ segments.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `stroke()` on each segment, not at the very end and there is no other possiblity.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this solution is 10x slower.

Answer (score 0):

Probably will have to make each segment it's own line. That or figure out how to make a custom shape with the same sort of gradient.